Proof AM ⊆ NP/poly
Adleman's theorem proves that BPP ⊆ P/poly. It is implied here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur%E2%80%93Merlin_protocol) that AM ⊆ NP/poly.

BPP = BP $\cdot$ P ⊆ P/poly
AM = BP $\cdot$ NP ⊆ NP/poly

Proving 2. uses the argument in the proof of BPP ⊆ P/poly except now inside the Pr
(probabilistic for all) quantifier, it is an NP predicate. I'm struggling to do this replacement in 1. to prove 2. and I couldn't find any paper that explicitly does it.

What does $BP \cdot P$ mean?  What does $BP \cdot NP$ mean?  Please define the notation you are using.

@D.W. This is a standard class operator. See e.g. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21602/a-good-reference-for-complexity-class-operators .

It really is the same argument as for BPP. Let $L$ be an AM language, thus there exists an NP predicate $R(w,r)$ and a polynomial $p(n)$ such that
for any $w\in\{0,1\}^n$,
$$\begin{align}
w\in L&\implies\Pr_{r\in\{0,1\}^{p(n)}}[R(w,r)]\ge\tfrac23,\\
w\notin L&\implies\Pr_{r\in\{0,1\}^{p(n)}}[R(w,r)]\le\tfrac13.
\end{align}$$

Reduce the probability of error below $2^{-n}$: There is $S\in\mathrm{NP}$ and a polynomial $q(n)$ such that for $w\in\{0,1\}^n$,
$$\begin{align}
w\in L&\implies\Pr_{s\in\{0,1\}^{q(n)}}[S(w,s)]>1-2^{-n},\\
w\notin L&\implies\Pr_{s\in\{0,1\}^{q(n)}}[S(w,s)]<2^{-n};
\end{align}$$
that is,
$$\Pr_{s\in\{0,1\}^{q(n)}}\bigl[\neg(S(w,s)\iff w\in L)\bigr]<2^{-n}.$$

This is shown by taking a majority vote among $O(n)$ independent samples. Using the Chernoff–Hoeffding bound, there is a constant $c$ (it should work to take $c>18\ln2\approx12{.}5$, but the value is not important) such that
$$\begin{align}
w\in L&\implies\Pr_{r_1,\dots,r_{cn}\in\{0,1\}^{p(n)}}\bigl[|\{i:R(w,r_i)\}|\ge\tfrac c2n\bigr]\ge1-2^{-(n+1)},\\
w\notin L&\implies\Pr_{r_1,\dots,r_{cn}\in\{0,1\}^{p(n)}}\bigl[|\{i:R(w,r_i)\}|\ge\tfrac c2n\bigr]\le2^{-(n+1)}.
\end{align}$$
Thus, it suffices to take $q(n)=cnp(n)$ and
$$S(w,r_1,\dots,r_{cn})\iff\bigl|\{i:R(w,r_i)\}\bigr|\ge\tfrac c2n.$$
You need to check that $S\in\mathrm{NP}$: a witness for $S(w,r_1,\dots,r_{cn})$ can be a subset $I\subseteq[cn]$ of size $\ge cn/2$ and a sequence of witnesses for $R(w,r_i)$, $i\in I$.

Apply the union bound: For a given $n$, we have
$$\begin{multline}\Pr_{s\in\{0,1\}^{q(n)}}\bigl[\exists w\in\{0,1\}^n\,\neg(S(w,s)\iff w\in L)\bigr]\\
\le\sum_{w\in\{0,1\}^n}\Pr_{s\in\{0,1\}^{q(n)}}\bigl[\neg(S(w,s)\iff w\in L)\bigr]<2^n\cdot2^{-n}=1,
\end{multline}$$
thus there exists $s_n\in\{0,1\}^{q(n)}$ such that
$$w\in L\iff S(w,s_n).$$
Taking $s_n$ as advice, this shows $L\in\mathrm{NP/poly}$.


You sould write research paper based on this answer.

Definitely. This is insanely helpful!
